# What does "technical dynamics" means?

Tags: stocks, terminology

Example usage: "Following a perfect storm of negative technical dynamics, recent spinoff SnakeOil is a coiled spring ready to double over the next year."

I assume it has to do with technical analysis, but I haven't found a clear definition anywhere and the definitions I'm guessing don't give that sentence any sense.

Comment: Can you tell us where you ran across this quote?

Comment: At an idea posted on ValueInvestorsClub.com.

Answer (score 3):

It's a somewhat vague term for "series of technically related events". Here it means the stock has gone down a lot, and someone attributes this to a "spiral" or "cascade" of negative technical signals that accompanied and possibly exacerbated the selling (e.g., a downtrend, then a loss of critical support, then a capitulation). Now, they believe the stock is very oversold and could start a new uptrend.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is one of the best [Weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) I ever see. It is used to trick the listener to derive their own conclusion than provide any solid meaning.

I doubt you will find explicit definition for "technical dynamic", as weasel words, it is meant to create [framing effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_effect_(psychology)), many people will fall into the trap and related the *technical* with [Technical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis). While relating *dynamics* to positive movements (which is a wrong perception).

> *Following* a **perfect storm** of *negative* **technical** *dynamics*, **recent**
>   *spinoff* **SnakeOil** is a **coiled spring** *ready* to *double over* **the next year**.

Break down the sentence, you will find a verb follows a metaphorical noun, but none of them gives you an affirmative conclusion. E.g. there is no such things as "**negative [dynamic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dynamic)**"; while "**the next year**" doesn't mean the next whole year, but can be forever.

Comment: Thanks. That sentence does sound like a pitch.